# PHP create savable PDF

Tags: php, pdf

I know, it is posible to create PDF's from PHP. fpdf, tcpdf, ezpdf, zend_pdf are some examples. Al those libraries does not support creating a "savable pdf".

I mean by that, a pdf with some input fields, and after entering the fields, just save the complete pdf, with the data.

Anybody idea's?

Alessandro

Comment: TCPDF does support input fields, doesn't it??

Answer (score 4):

Check out [Webkit to PDF](http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/). You would simply need to create an HTML page from the input and then use Webkit to PDF to convert it.